# A Call for Inclusionism

Tags: discussion, subjective-questions

In the [latest SO blog post Joel Spolsky](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/andreessen-horowitz-invests-in-stack-exchange/) states:

> We don’t allow opinionated questions, because they descend into flame wars that don’t help people who need an answer right now.

This is false. Being subjective does not always mean that discussion, argument, and opinions can not be insightful. Certainly disrespectful flame wars have no place on SO, but that doesn't mean subjective discussion should be banned. I've never seen a personal insult on SO and there are other mechanisms to take care of that potential problem.

Please reconsider this policy. There's no lack of bytes or limit on space for helpful content here. On the [Asking help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) there is mention that open ended questions "push other questions off the front page". That's not a valid reason to exclude potentially helpful content. [Please let's not be like wikipedia with their deletionists and strict notoriety requirements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deletionism_and_inclusionism_in_Wikipedia). Let's practice inclusionism.

Many users have found great answers and up voted many "[What's the best ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what%27s%20the%20best)" questions, even though they are often closed. They have tremendous value and should be allowed. They are often have concise useful community reviewed and voted upon answers.

We the users will be better served with a more liberal inclusion policy of respectful subjective content. Opinions can have value.

Comment: Joel, as always, oversimplifies. But, no, we won't reconsider, as it has been shown in the past that the *class* of questions do not work in the context of a strict Q&A platform.

Comment: This has been discussed to death on both [meta.se] and here before. "We the users" is your sole opinion; please don't presume that you can speak for the millions of others here. There's an old saying about opinions related to a backside-located orifice and bad smells that applies perfectly here - everybody's got one and they all stink. Allowing opinion-based posts here would benefit no one and would detract from the value of the site. If you want to get opinion-based answers,  post your question on one of the hundreds of other sites that allow those types of question.

Comment: Note that there is even an SE site for *certain* "What's the best" questions. Software Reccommendations SE

Comment: It should also be noted that these are *Question and Answer* sites, not *Questions and Opinions or Advice or Answers*. There's no definitive answer to a subjective or opinion-based question, and that violates the basic goals and purpose of these sites.. And if you've never seen a personal insult at SO, you're not paying attention. I see them frequently in comments, and flag them for mods to delete.

Comment: opinions are not answers.  By the way, whats a good shampoo?

Comment: Opinion based answers also have an annoying common tendency to become out of date as soon as the next best tech comes along

Comment: Ask "Whats better, Java or C#" somewhere (please not here, please) and you'll see why we don't like opinion-based questions here :)

Comment: Having a site like SO available does mean you never have to code alone anymore.  But that's all it does, it doesn't necessarily work both ways.

Comment: [Is there a problem with Stack Overflow when extremely useful, massively upvoted questions get closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92980/is-there-a-problem-with-stack-overflow-when-extremely-useful-massively-upvoted)

Comment: @Plutonix I use nothing but Head & Shoulders Dry Scalp Care. If I skip it more than a day, I can provide a lot of fake snow...

Comment: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: In addition to the existing reasons, the SE network attracts experts *because* of the core focus.  Allowing these types of questions would actively drive away the very people that make SE great, as they would deluge the site.  Allow questions because of awesome expertise, ignoring *why* the expertise is present, and you just turn the site into another failed ghost town.  It's ultimately a self-defeating proposal to allow this class of questions.

Answer (score 6):

Subjective questions are not allowed as part of the Stack Exchange model because they *tend* to spur such arguments. While it may not happen every time, poll-style and recommendation questions can cause problems that are not always easy to deal with.

We sometimes let it slide on Meta because that's the nature of the topics discussed here, but on the main site, they're not allowed. Those examples you cite are quite old (many are from over 6 years ago), and standards have changed. On a small scale, it's easy to deal with spam and flame wars, but when you get hundreds of thousands of questions daily across the network, that kind of moderation doesn't scale.

It's easier to close an opinion-based question and prevent arguments than it is to deal with every answer that gets the slightest bit out of hand on millions of questions. More than anything, it's about the scale and the fact that people get really defensive about that score next to their name.

Answer (score 4):

> This is false.

No it isn't.

> I've never seen a personal insult on SO

You didn't so far? You'll so soon.

> ..there are other mechanisms to take care of that potential problem.

You mean, flags? That moderators checking them? Imagine it's a forum and people always discussing in opinion based questions. Probably we need +5000 moderators to handle that flags.

SO is a website for basically, questions about programming. If opinion-based questions are allowed then you can't stop discussions between people. It'll going to mess up. SO is not a *forum* that's why subjective-questions are not allowed and this is the difference between SO and a regular forum.